# Redirecting when catching an error from axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to redirect to an error page I made when I catch an error from an axiosRequest. 
So anyway, I got a .js full of methods like this:

```
export const getPublication = async (id) => {
    const idJSON = {"id": id,}
    return await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'users/getPublicationByID',
        data: idJSON
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Hello: " + error); //this alert shows up correctly
          this.context.history.replace('/error') //this isnt working
      });
}
```

Then inside my .js pages I import that file and perform my requests.
When I get an error I do get the alert inside the catch in the previous code but I'm not able to redirect my page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `this.props` to this function from component where you imported like

```
getPublication(id,this.props);
```

and your function

```
export const getPublication = async (id,props) => {
    const idJSON = {"id": id,}
    return await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'users/getPublicationByID',
        data: idJSON
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Hello: " + error); //this alert shows up correctly
          props.history.push('/path');          
      });
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you I ended up doint it this way.

Comment: I'm trying to also set the state like this: `props.history.push({
                pathname: '/error',
                state: { hasError: true, coding: '123' }
              })`                                                                                                                                                       It does't seem to work though, I mean it does redirect but it doesn't set the state properly.

Comment: How you are accessing passed state in redirected component ?

Comment: Just made another question specifying the situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109227/unable-to-change-state-when-using-redirection-with-history-push

Answer (score 2):

can you try this :

```
 .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Hello: " + error);
          window.location.replace("/error")
  });
```

If you don't want to refresh you can use `history.push` from react-router

Answer (score 1):

You are using an arrow function so `this` in that context is a window or undefined (if you are in JS strict mode"). You will probably need to pass the history as an argument to the `getPublication` function. Another solution (if you are sure that the function or class you are invoking your function on top of has valid history.replace) is to change the arrow function to regular function. In this case, this will refer to the scoped function/class.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getPublication = async (id) => {
const idJSON = {"id": id,}
return await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'users/getPublicationByID',
    data: idJSON
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      return response.data
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      alert("Hello: " + error); //this alert shows up correctly
      this.setstate({dataError:true})
  });
```

}

and in render block :

```
  render() {
if (this.state.dataError) {
  // redirect to error if axios return error
  return <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/error" }} />;
}

}
```