# Unable to change state when using redirection with history.push

Tags: reactjs

I got the following method:

```
export const getPublication = async (id, props) => {
    const idJSON = {"id": id,}
    return await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'users/getPublicationByID',
        data: idJSON
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          alert(error.response.status); // Works fine 
          props.history.push({
            pathname: '/error',
            state: { hasError: true, coding: error.response.status }
          })
      });
}
```

Now, this method seems to work fine as it redirects me from the page I was to '/error' when an error is caught. However, the error page doesn't seem to update its coding variable.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            hasError: false,
            coding: props.coding
        };
    }

    render(){
        const { t } = this.props;
            var codeMsg = t('errors.errorCode') + this.state.coding;
            alert(codeMsg); // says it's undefined!
            return ( 
                ...
            );     
    }

}

export default withTranslation()(ErrorBoundary);
```

Comment: mm ok, my question is basically how to change the state inside my component using the history push.

Comment: this.props.location.state.coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` provided to routed components is available at `location.state`

```
coding: props.location.state.coding
```

[docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation)